# How to reference an array from another function Objective-C

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c, closures, nsmutablearray

I have declared array in SomeClass.h It's a global variable isn't it?

`@property (nonnull, nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *additional_tabs;`

Below I declared 2 function where I use this array.

`- (id _Nullable)initFromJSON:(NSDictionary *_Nullable)dictionary;`

`- (void)moreTabs:(NSMutableArray *_Nullable)a;`

Below is if-statement I used inside `initFromJSON` function.

```
if ([Tools isNonullValueForKey:[dictionary valueForKey:@"additional_tabs"]]) {
        _additional_tabs = [NSMutableArray new]; //really I need them?
        _additional_tabs = [dictionary valueForKey:@"additional_tabs"];
            
            NSLog(@"additionalTabCount (initJSON) = %lu", [_additional_tabs count]);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < [_additional_tabs count]; i++) {
                 
                 if ([Tools isNonullValueForKey:[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"_id"]]) {
                     _additional_tab_id = [[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"_id"] objectAtIndex:i];
                 }
                     
                 if ([Tools isNonullValueForKey:[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"names"]]) {
                     NSDictionary *dic = [[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"names"] objectAtIndex:i];
                     _en_additional_tab_name = [dic valueForKey:@"en"];
                     _pl_additional_tab_name = [dic valueForKey:@"pl"];
                 }
                     
                 if ([Tools isNonullValueForKey:[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"url"]]) {
                     _additional_tab_url = [[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"url"] objectAtIndex:i];
                 }
                
                NSLog(@"%@ %d %@ %@ %@ %@", @"pos", i,  @"id: ", _additional_tab_id, @"url: ", _additional_tab_url);
            }
        }
```

And this `[_additional_tabs count]` have 17.
But in function `moreTabs`:

```
    NSLog(@"additional tabs count: %lu",[_additional_tabs count]);
    for (int i = 1; i < [_additional_tabs count]; i++) {
    [a addObject:[[VCTab alloc] initWithIdAndTypeAndUrl:[[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"_id"] objectAtIndex:i] :VCTabAdditional :[[_additional_tabs valueForKey:@"url"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
}
```

return `[_additional_tabs count]` with nil... look like is different array or cleared?

I would be very grateful for your help :)
All the best

Comment: It isn't global, it is an instance property. Are you using the same instance of your class in both cases?  Also, from a style point of view, prefer camelCase to _ in objective c identifiers, and I suggest you always use the setter/getter via `self.` rather than accessing the backing iVar directly with _ unless you have a good reason.

Comment: You should also look out for asynchronous execution. Your first function mentions JSON. Is it retrieving data from the network? Are you calling your second function before then network operation is complete?

Comment: Yes you need self._additional_tabs = blahblahblah in order to guarantee that it is retained. And you don’t need the first line with [NSDictionary new]

Comment: @Paulw11 @KeithKnauber I added "self" and array still return nil. If I used breakpoints on debug the first method is JSON and print ids, urls and names for response in logs. Next step is addObject in moreTabs(). I used this method in LeftMenuViewController and is look: ```Conference *cf = [Conference new];
        [cf moreTabs:vcTabs];
        [self logArray]; ```